# Run github workflow if there is a comment

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to update my pull request by pushing, check if there is comment and run workflow

```
name: Update

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [synchronize]
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  update:
    name: Update
    if: contains(github.event.pull_request_comment.comment, 'Here is a comment:')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leRt5.png)

I want to check if there was created comment before I push something new

I know that github.event.pull_request_comment it's something that following the creating of the comments but I need something to check if it was already created

Comment: if you want to trigger a wf when a comment is created/updated, you should listen to this event also https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#issue_comment

Answer (score 1):

I would try using this action [peter-evans/find-comment](https://github.com/peter-evans/find-comment) to check for the string in your PR's comments and then use that in your if check.

```yaml
jobs:
  check-comment:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      comment-id: ${{ steps.fc.outputs.comment-id }}
    steps:
      - name: Find Comment
        uses: peter-evans/find-comment@v2
        id: fc
        with:
          issue-number: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
          body-includes: 'Here is a comment:'

  run-other-workflow:
    needs: [check-comment]
    uses: ./other-workflow.yml
    if: ${{ needs.check-comment.outputs.comment-id != 0 }}
```

The first job will find the comment in your PR if it exists, the second job will run if that comment is found. [ref](https://github.com/peter-evans/find-comment#outputs)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but you could maybe use the [issue_comment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#issue_comment) webhook to trigger the workflow?

You could specify it so that only creating a comment triggers the workflow.